# Mysql - migrated new website and getting errors

Tags: mysql

I need help with MySQL database. I migrated a website to a new hosting provider and now im getting this error.

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/21/11026521/html/index.php on line 106 (on the test site)

I;m not a technical person but im trying to fix this issue. Can  someone help.

I'm not sure what else information to provide you with.

Comment: Was your database also migrated?

Comment: I would suggest that you hire a technical person. Your question is outside of the Stackoverfow scope.

Comment: The warning means, that you got a `false` instead of a resource. This also means, that you did not check, wether your query was successful after you sent it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0):

Most important info you didn't provide is how you "migrated" your website, especially the database.

Did you keep all your table schematics? This is really important. Just make sure all your rows in all your tables are in the same order, have the same name, accept the same datatype and maybe even have the same constraints as before.

If you could post some snippet of your php and the corresponding mysql table layout, we can go into depth with error analysis here.